# How to make .css file to run alongside the .html file in Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have a .html file which is identical to the one on CSS Zen Garden, a .css file which I restyled to my liking. Those two files and all materials are put in the same folder on Desktop. The page opens and is styled when using Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox, however there is no styling whatsoever when trying to open the .html file with Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge.

How do I resolve this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>CSS Zen Garden: The Beauty of CSS Design</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="style.css?v=8may2013">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS" 
href="http://www.csszengarden.com/zengarden.xml">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="author" content="Dave Shea">
<meta name="description" content="A demonstration of what can be 
accomplished visually through CSS-based design.">
<meta name="robots" content="all">


<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="script/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
```

Comment: You should at least show us the relevant lines of your code. In this case, that's most likely the one where you include the CSS file.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, I've found the fix... The creators included a line to make the file work for IE/ ME.

Comment: Try removing the `?v=8may2013` and see if that works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As it turns out, I didn't take a look at the HTML well enough.
Deleting the... comments? around the  line made it work in IE and also Microsoft Edge.

From

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="script/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

To...

```
<script src="script/html5shiv.js"></script>
```

should work...

Comment: I don't think it's related with CSS not being loaded. `<!--[if lt IE 9]` is pre-IE9 conditional comment, means in any IE that is lower than 9 this JS will be included